# How to run Serenity BDD Test cases in IE and chrome

Tags: serenity-bdd

Can some one help me to know how to run Serenity BDD test cases in IE and  chrome browser, I tried  the way it said in it's doc and other posts at stack over flow, did not work for .  I am using Serenity BDD version is 1.1.1. Help from any one you will be appreciated very much.

Comment: What have you tried? This is very general and is hard to answer. Sounds like you might need to do some more research so you can ask a more specific question. What does "did not work" mean? Did it produce errors?

Comment: THANK YOU .  Here is what tried , my test cases run fine in fire fox but I tried in IE & Chrome by following instructions on http://thucydides.info/docs/serenity-staging/#_serenity_webdriver_support_in_junit

Comment: Also tried at command lline by these commands and in command line I tried mvn clean verify serenity:aggregate  -Dwebdriver.driver=iexplorer, for these I have been getting following error net.thucydides.core.webdriver.UnsupportedDriverException: Could not instantiate class org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver

Comment: I tried following at https://java.net/projects/thucydides/forums/user-forum/topics/402-Using-Internet-Explorer-with-Thucydides to edit sureFire plugin in POM file, still I am getting same error

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create a **serenity.properties** file in the project root, with the line driver=chrome or driver=iexplorer

You can also use the same arguments as system properties.  Here's the full list of settings:
http://thucydides.info/docs/serenity/#_running_serenity_tests_from_the_command_line

Comment: Thanks, I am testing these in hub-node configuration, I was able to run test case in chrome at hub by inserting line driver=chrome in serenity.property file but where as for IE , inserting line driver=iexplorer did not work & getting following error - net.thucydides.core.webdriver.UnsupportedDriverException: Could not instantiate class org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
 at com.steps.TestOneSteps.Navigate_To_home_page(TestOneSteps.java:15)
 at com.features.New.TestOne.Test_One(TestOne.java:84)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4Test

Comment: Great, Chrome is much easier to get running than Internet Explorer.  On your IE node, you'll also need to apply the following configuration changes:
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#required-configuration